# Plotting a frequency response from biquad filter

Tags: c, filter, plot, response, frequency

This is a hard one and although I can think of a few kludge methods of doing it, I have a feeling there is a clean mathematical method, although I am having difficulty inventing it myself.

I have a number of parameters which control (software) biquad filters for audio. Essentially there are just 3 parameters, frequency, gain and Q (or bandwidth). In audio terms, the frequency represents the center frequency of the filter. The gain represents whether this frequency is boosted or cut (a gain of 0 results in no change to the audio passing through the filter). Q represents the width of the filter - IE a very wide filter might affect frequencies far away from the center frequency, whereas a narrow (low Q) filter will only affect frequencies close to the center frequency.The filters take the form of a bell curve, or at least thats an approximation, whether its mathematically accurate I am not sure.

I want to display the characteristics of these filters graphically - display a graph of gain against frequency. There are several of these filters applied to the audio channel, and I want to be able to add the different result graphs, to produce an overall graph (IE a graph summing all the components of the combined filters). But I also want to be able to access the individual filters graphs.

I can handle adding the component graphs into a single 'total' graph, but how to produce the original x-y graph from the filter parameters escapes me. I will draw bitmaps so all I need is to be able to create arrays of the form frequency[x]=y. Im doing this in C so I don't have the mathematical tools in matlab etc. So I might have a filter with a center frequency of say 1000 (Hz), a gain of say 20 (db or linear I understand how to convert that), and a Q of say 3. The Q factor is relative and does not have to be exactly mathematically correct if that causes any complication.

It seems like a quite simple mathematical function but maths is not my strong point and I don't know enough - I have been messing round with sine functions etc but its not working and I suspect is probably wasting processing power by over complicating the maths (although I might be wrong there).

TIA, Pete

Comment: how important is accuracy? you mention it's approximately normal, biquad filters can be bell shaped but they're pretty far from normal I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my doubts about the relationships between biquad filters, Q values, and bell curves.  But I'll put those aside and just tell you how to draw a bell curve, since that's what you asked.

From this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), the equation for a bell curve is

[image]

where for your application

- `a` corresponds to the gain
- `b` determines the center frequency
- `2c^2` is related to Q (larger values will make the curve wider)

The C code below computes a sample bell curve. For this example, the numbers were chosen based on drawing into a window that is 250 pixels wide by 200 pixels high, with a coordinate system where the origin {0,0} is at the bottom left corner.

```
int width  = 250;
int height = 200;

int bellCurve[width];       // the output array that holds the f(x) values

double gain    =  180;      // the 'a' value, determines how high the peak is from the baseline
double offset  =   10;      // the 'd' value, determines the y coordinate of the baseline
double qFactor = 1000;      // the '2c^2' value, determines how fat the curve is
double center  =  100;      // the 'b' value, determines the x coordinate of the peak
double dx;

for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ )
{
    dx = x - center;
    bellCurve[x] = gain * exp( -( dx * dx ) / qFactor ) + offset;
}
```

Plotting the curve results in an image like this where the peak is at `x=100, y=10+180=190`

[image]

Comment: Thanks to all 3 answers all of which are useful. I know about bode plots from electronics but didnt make the connection and it helps me understand the problem. Idea to stretch precalculated plot is a good one that I might end up using to some degree. Measuring response idea will be great to check accuracy of my plots if I use an approximation (ie the bell curve thing). And bell curve answer is superb and certainly answers the question with help writing the code, which I highly appreciate. Interesting what you say about your doubts that the bell curve fits the biquad shape, could you elaborate?

Comment: Further to previous comment, I did find some code here http://www.christian.sakui.de/projekte/biquadPlot which the author does what I want accurately in javascript. But even after conversion to C and (simple) optimization (to prevent repeated calculations of trig functions), its horribly expensive, and hogs like a dog (when run 25 times per second on 20 instances over 16 channels = 8kHz). Comments on the getBiquadImaginaryPart and getBiquadRealPart functions in http://www.christian.sakui.de/projekte/biquadPlot/code.js would be interesting if anyone has time. Is it necessarily this complex?

Comment: Hence maybe the bell curve idea, if its a reasonable fit, might work better in my app. With the code above I can calculate both and display simultaneously so compare.

Comment: @Pete -- The purpose of my opening comment was to alert future readers that I was answering, "How do I plot a bell curve?" as opposed to, "How do I plot the frequency response of a biquad filter?" Since you seem to be well aware of the difference between the two, I was happy to provide the answer to the former, in the hopes that it might assist you in some small way in finding the answer to the latter. A quick survey of the literature convinced me that it would take a great deal of study before I could answer the latter. So I have provided what assistance I could, and the rest is up to you :)

Comment: @338, indeed, you answered the question I was hoping to get answered so no complaints from me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could input a unit impulse (an array of all zeros, except one element=1.0) into your digital filters, treating them as black boxes. Then FFT the impulse response output array to get the frequency response of the filter. Plotting the magnitude of the complex frequency samples will give you a pretty picture. Python+numpy+matplotlib would probably be an easier way to go about it. You will need to know the sampling period to get meaningful plots.

Comment: It doesn't sound like OP has the filters themselves, black-boxed or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is the bode plot of the filter. This is non trivial to calculate yourself, a cursory search for a library to do it for you in C yielded nothing. If accuracy is not important and you can approximate the shape once and stretch it based on the parameters of the particular filter. For example, you might have a normalized array of relative values and construct a new curve (array) based on the parameters of the filter and the base curve you generated earlier.

The base curve could be generated from MATLAB if you can or Wolfram Alpha or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in javascript.

http://www.earlevel.com/main/2013/10/13/biquad-calculator-v2/

The filter you describe is the 'peak' filter. Use the log scale to display frequencies.

—Tom